# space in CSS selectors? I have these two selectors:

Tags: css, space

What is the difference between these two:

```
article.description

article .description
```

The first one does not have space between class and element. But the second one has

Answer (score 3):

1. Element which one is article and has `description` class
2. Element with `description` class who is child of article element

https://jsfiddle.net/ha5eepdo/

Comment: Can you please provide a link to a reference?

Comment: This is the correct answer. It shouldn't have been downvoted

Comment: @RichardHamilton Yes you are right, this is the correct answer!

Comment: @IceJOKER Thanks for the link +1 for you. I did not know that before

Answer (score 0):

**`article .description`**: Means that those CSS settings are applied to any HTML element with the class `.description` that is inside an `article`.

**`article.description`**: Means that those CSS settings are applied to `article` elements that has `.description` class.

Answer (score 0):

`article.description`  should select only "article" elements that have a class of "description"

`article .description`  should select all children of "article" elements that have a class of "description"

Answer (score 0):

`article.description`: This finds all article elements that have a class of description.

`article .description`: This finds all elements with class `description` that are descendants of the article tag.

The first one is a simple `class` selector

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors

The second one is referred to as the `descendant` selector. Here is information from MDN

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors